# Ansible: How to get output with more details

Tags: ansible

I am wondering is it possible to get output from a playbook with details like one runs ansible command line. For example, I am checking user's privileges running dzinfo command.

`ansible server_name -m shell -a "/usr/bin/dzinfo some_user" -u user_name -b -k -K`

The output is:

```
 Role Name        Avail Restricted Env 
---------------  ----- -------------- 
some-details                          

Effective rights:
    Password login
    Non password login
    Allow normal shell
    Visible

   Audit level:
    AuditIfPossible

Always permit login:
    false


 PAM Application  Avail Source Roles         
 ---------------  ----- -------------------- 
crond            Yes   some-role              
login            Yes   some-role             
sshd             Yes   some-role
```

Now, once I run playbook, the only info I am receiving back is :

```
PLAY RECAP 
some_server            : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Is there any way to get detailed output running playbook? Like one from above where I can see details of privileges?

Comment: Use `verbose` mode using -v, -vvv or -vvvv when running ansible-playbook. As well you can `register` the output of each step into a variable to understand more. The register store the response into shell_result variable.

Comment: verbose works nice with getent . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can `register` the result of `command` task, and then use a
subsequent `debug` task to display it.  For example, the following
playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - command: /usr/bin/dzinfo some_user
      register: dzinfo_output

    - debug:
        var: dzinfo_output.stdout_lines
```

Might produce output like this:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [command] ********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dzinfo_output.stdout_lines": [
        " Role Name        Avail Restricted Env ",
        "---------------  ----- -------------- ",
        "some-details                          ",
        "",
        "Effective rights:",
        "    Password login",
        "    Non password login",
        "    Allow normal shell",
        "    Visible",
        "",
        "   Audit level:",
        "    AuditIfPossible",
        "",
        "Always permit login:",
        "    false",
        "",
        "",
        " PAM Application  Avail Source Roles         ",
        " ---------------  ----- -------------------- ",
        "crond            Yes   some-role              ",
        "login            Yes   some-role             ",
        "sshd             Yes   some-role "
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0
```

Comment: where should I define variable, as this dzinfo_output.stdout_lines I believe must be define

Comment: Do you see the `register` directive in the `command` task? For more details, see [the ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables).

Comment: Thanks for that info